# restore multiple .trn logs in SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL server 2008 R2 and need to restore 36 .trn logs to a database. I have restored the first 4 using the restore transaction log functionality in SSMS (right click database > tasks > restore > transaction log). Is there a way to restore them all in order using this tool or with a script? The .trn files are in a folder on a remote server. I do not not need to restore all the files in the folder, only ones between specific dates.

Thanks in advance